# Only one file showing preview in my multiple images preview javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one problem in javascript. I am showing preview of multiple file choosing in javascript. Its working for one file input, if i insert another file input its not showing preview. i am new to javascript, please help me

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

//Check File API support
if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
{
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("files1");

    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById("result");

        for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];

            //Only pics
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
              continue;

            var picReader = new FileReader();

            picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                var picFile = event.target;

                var div = document.createElement("div");

                div.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter your file name' name='file_name[]''></br><img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";

                output.insertBefore(div,null);            

            });

             //Read the image
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }                               

    });
}
else
{
    console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
}
}


window.onload = function(){

//Check File API support
if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
{
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("files2");

    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById("result1");

        for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];

            //Only pics
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
              continue;

            var picReader = new FileReader();

            picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                var picFile = event.target;

                var div = document.createElement("div");

                div.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Enter your file name' name='file_name[]''></br><img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";

                output.insertBefore(div,null);            

            });

             //Read the image
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }                               

    });
}
else
{
    console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
}
}


</script>
```

HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<article>
<?php 

    if(isset($aquery)){
        echo $aquery;
    }

?>
    <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
    <input id="files1" type="file" name="gallery[]" multiple/>

    <output id="result" />


     <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
    <input id="files2" type="file" name="floorplan[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    <output id="result1" />


</article>
</form>
```

In this i have two files differentiate in Id's, Its showing only preview for one files. I want to show both files. Is there any other idea to solve this problem

Comment: It look like your included your script twice.

Comment: I have two files so i include two times, i differentiate with ID's

Comment: You can refactor this code to contain only one event handler and you set it in two places for two different elements.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i got solution for this, i set attr in input file and separated by if condition.
if($('#floorplanId').attr("data-change") === 'floorEvent'){ #above code }